# How to prove C([−π, π]) is included in span ({cos nx, n ∈ N ∪ {0}} ∪ {sin nx, n ∈ N})?

Tags: functional-analysis

Considering L2([−π, π]) Real space. Taking f ∈ C([−π, π]) y fixed ε > 0 dividing in three parts ε/3 and:
1st) Using first part to approach f by another function g, extending it in a periodical and continuous way, modifying f around edges in proper way.
2nd) Considering with the 2nd part to approach g with another function h differentiable
3rd) Using the 3rd part and the results of convergence from Nagle, Saff & Snider book to approach h by a Fourier series approach enough. In ||.||2

Comment: Would you mean **closed** span?

Comment: Yes, considering C([−π, π]) the set of continuous functions of  [−π, π] in R.

Comment: Another question is: then, could we conclude {cos nx, n ∈ N ∪ {0}} ∪ {sin nx, n ∈ N} is a Schauder base in L2([−π, π]) considered as complex space?

Comment: Do you know about the Fejer means of the Fourier series, and how  they converge uniformly to a continuous periodic function on $[-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: You mean the Fejer’s Theorem: Let f : [−π, π] → R be a continuous function with f(−π) = f(π). Then
the Fourier series of f (C,1)-converges to f in C([−π, π], R), where C([−π, π], R) is the
metric space of continuous functions from [−π, π] to R.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel